# RegEx problems with double quotes

Tags: php, regex

I´m using the following RegEx to divide a string in keys and values:

**String**:

```
type="post" id="1" text="Blog Post"
```

**Regex**:

```
/(?<name>\\S+)=["']?(?P<value>(?:.(?!["']?\\s+(?:\\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']?/u
```

That works fine as long as each value has at minimum 2 characters. I the value is only 1 character long (like id here) I get a **quote after the number**. So for this example with ID I get the following output:

```
type => post
id => 1"
text => Blog Post
```

I´ve no idea where my bug in the RegEx is. Maybe somebody can give me a hint?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks a bit like you're trying to parse markup with regex, which is never a good idea. You need a DOM parser to consume markup.

Comment: No, I´m not parsing a DOM. I´m looking for Shortcodes (like in Wordpress) in Text to process it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the latest point is redundant.
Could you try this:

```
/(?<name>\\S+)=["']?(?P<value>(?:.(?!["']?\\s+(?:\\S+)=|[>"']))+)["']?/u
```

I don't konw how you are using this regex, but I think you can use this option:

```
/(\w+)=["']?([^"']+)["']/ug
```

Or provide me more info.

Comment: Hm.. I´ve created a regex101 page where you can see the issue (attribute "error"): https://regex101.com/r/yX2uW2/1